# Segmentation fault in snprintf() c

Tags: c, char, printf

Im trying to create a function with return a `char *` with the current date and time. But im getting the segmentation fault while usig snprintf.
Here's the part of the code.

```
int buf_size = 20;
char *n = NULL;
snprintf(n, buf_size , "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", 1900+st.tm_year,
         st.tm_mon+1, st.tm_mday, st.tm_hour, st.tm_min, st.tm_sec);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` is `NULL`, so you're attempting to copy to an invalid memory location.

Consider replacing the second line with

```
char n[80]; /* at least enough characters for the buffer */
```

or, more suitable for returning a string

```
char *n = ( char * ) malloc( 80 * sizeof( char ) );
```

Comment: The OP says they are trying to *return* the formatted string, so this will only move the problem around.

Comment: In C, do not cast the result of `malloc`, it can hide bugs due to failure to `#include <stdlib.h>`.  (It's necessary in C++, though.) In all C-family languages, `sizeof(char) == 1` *by definition* and therefore writing it explicitly is a bad code smell.

Comment: @yarokas To use `malloc` one must `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @yarokas - first, edit your code fragment to include the function declaration. You'll get more precise answers. Second, a function with a return type of `char *` can return a variable of type char [].

Comment: @Zack Yes, i forgot about the lib.

Answer (score 3):

`snprintf` does not allocate the buffer for you.  You set `n` to `NULL`, so it cheerfully tries to write to a nonexistent memory location and crashes.

You want to use [`asprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) instead.  If your C library does not have `asprintf`, it can be implemented using `malloc` and `snprintf`.  I leave doing that as an exercise.

Comment: Tried `asprintf` it didn't resolve the problem, even with `malloc`. But `snprintf` with `malloc` works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory that would be pointed to by pointer p and where you are going to write data.

Instead of

```
char *n = NULL;
```

you should write

```
char *n = malloc( buf_size );
```

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer.

Let `snprintf()` determine buffer size.

```
int buf_size = snprintf(NULL, 0 , "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", 1900+st.tm_year,
     st.tm_mon+1, st.tm_mday, st.tm_hour, st.tm_min, st.tm_sec);
if (buf_size < 0) {
  Hanlde_EncodingError();
}

char n[buf_size + 1];  // or char *n = malloc(buf_size + 1);

snprintf(n, buf_size , "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", 1900+st.tm_year,
     st.tm_mon+1, st.tm_mday, st.tm_hour, st.tm_min, st.tm_sec);
```